# How to add or change a Class (not an instance)?

Tags: python

I would like to set an attribute to an class object directly, without creating an instance, e.g. having an alternative name that can be accessed like the __ **name** __ attribute:

```
class Foo:
    pass

> Foo.__name__
Foo
```

But this doesn't work:

```
some_file.py:

class Foo:
    alternativ_name = __name__ + "_ending"

print(Foo.alternativ_name)
```

This prints:

```
__main___ending
```

If I try it in the interactive Console, it returns something else again:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   alt_name = __name__ + "_ending"
...
>>> Foo.alt_name
'builtins_ending'
```

What I would like to achive is:

```
class Foo:
    alt_name = __name__ + "_ending"
Foo.alt_name
```

should return:

```
'Foo_ending'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `Foo.alt_name` is not the same as `print(Foo.alt_name)`

Comment: Unless you are obsessed with doing it inline in the class body, what is wrong with simply adding a `Foo.alt_name = Foo.__name__ + "_ending"` after the class definition?

Comment: @donkopotamus I want to do it inline to inherit the behavior. Outside the class defintion it will not work for the child classes. Without inheritance I think it would be possible to not reference the __name__ attribute but just write 'alt_name = "Foo_ending" ' within the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foo.__name__` has not yet been created at the point you are trying to access it. Therefore, when you access `__name__` it gets the module's `__name__`. There are several ways you can solve this. One is by using a metaclass, but this is pretty overkill for just adding an attribute to a class. The second is to use a decorator on the class, and the third is to make `alt_name` a non-data descriptor or maybe a property.

Using a decorator:

```
def add_alt_name(template):
    def decorator(klass):
        klass.alt_name = template.format(klass.__name__)
        return klass
    return decorator

@add_alt_name(template="{}_ending")
class Foo:
    pass

print(Foo.alt_name)
```

Using a non-data descriptor:

```
class AlternativeName:
    def __init__(self, template, name="alt_name"):
        self.template = template
        self.name = "_" + name

    def __get__(self, instance, klass):
        try:
            return getattr(klass, self.name)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        alt_name = self.template.format(klass.__name__)
        setattr(klass, self.name, alt_name)
        return alt_name

class Foo:
    alt_name = AlternativeName(template="{}_ending")

print(Foo.alt_name)
```

Much simpler just to use a decorator.

Comment: Thanks! The decorator works for me fine with the class itself, but not for child classes (means, the return the alt_name of the father and not of themselfes). The descriptor works fine for me, means child classes will return their "own" alt_name. But I see, it's not realy a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `__name__` and `Foo.__name__` actually point to two different things. Using `__name__` within the `Foo` class still uses the global variable, and not `Foo.__name__`.

Within the class, it is not possible to explicitly reference the same class:

```
class Foo:
    alt_name = Foo.__name__ + "_ending"
    # raises NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

If you want the property on objects, you can do it during runtime, e.g. in the `__init__`. If you really want the property on the class itself, you can do that using metaclasses:

```
class Foo:
    class __metaclass__(type):
        @property
        def alt_name(cls):
            return cls.__name__ + "_ending"
```

Comment: If you're going to use a metaclass why not just set `alt_name` as an attribute in `__metaclass__.__init__` rather than using a property.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I tried to reference the class itself (would be like using "self" within the class definition, but I think thats not possible)  I didn't get the __metaclass__ solution to work. For me it seems there is no 'alt_name' attribute created to the Foo-class ("AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'alt_name'"). I'll try to tinker with the superclass thing a bit more.